# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$rootScope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the error below on my app

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
   at m.prototype.$digest (https://localhost:44301/angular.min.js:132:501)
   at m.prototype.$apply (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:135:159)
   at Anonymous function (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:19:315)
   at e (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:10)
   at d (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:19:236)
   at zc (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:23)
   at Yd (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:18:342)
   at Anonymous function (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:289:159)
   at j (https://localhost:44301/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2:26852)
   at k.fireWith (https://localhost:44301/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2:27609)
```

its only throw once when the app starts, and after I login to my active directory the app works fine across all views.

My app.js is like this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
        'pascalprecht.translate',       // Angular Translate
        'ngIdle',                       // Idle timer
        'AdalAngular',                  // ADAL JS Angular
        'ngRoute'                       // Routing
    ])
})();
```

and part of my config.js

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // Configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: true
    });

    $stateProvider

        .state('dashboards', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboards",
            templateUrl: "views/common/content.html",

        })
        .state('dashboards.dashboard_1', {
            url: "/dashboard_1",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard_1.html",
            requireADLogin: true,
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        {

                            serie: true,
                            name: 'angular-flot',
                            files: ['js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angles',
                            files: ['js/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angular-peity',
                            files: ['js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })

 adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
           {instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
               tenant: 'mysaasapp.onmicrosoft.com',
               clientId: '33e037a7-b1aa-42ab-9693-6c22d01ca338',
               extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1'
               //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
           },
           $httpProvider
           );
}
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .config(config)
    .run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
```

My index.html

```
<!--
* INSPINIA - Responsive Admin Theme
* Version 2.0
*
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="inspinia">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Page title set in pageTitle directive -->
    <title page-title></title>

    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main Inspinia CSS files -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="loadBefore" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<!-- ControllerAs syntax -->
<!-- Main controller with serveral data used in Inspinia theme on diferent view -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

<!-- Main view  -->
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- MetsiMenu -->
<script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<!-- Peace JS -->
<script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>

<!-- Main Angular scripts-->
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/angular-idle/angular-idle.js"></script>

<!--
 You need to include this script on any page that has a Google Map.
 When using Google Maps on your own site you MUST signup for your own API key at:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
 After your sign up replace the key in the URL below..
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQTpXj82d8UpCi97wzo_nKXL7nYrd4G70"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/adal/adal.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/adal/adal-angular.js"></script>

<!-- Anglar App Script -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/translations.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my content.html

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/navigation.html'"></div>

    <!-- Page wraper -->
    <!-- ng-class with current state name give you the ability to extended customization your view -->
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg {{$state.current.name}}">

        <!-- Page wrapper -->
        <div ng-include="'views/common/topnavbar.html'"></div>

        <!-- Main view  -->
        <div ui-view></div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div ng-include="'views/common/footer.html'"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- End page wrapper-->

    <!-- Right Sidebar -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/right_sidebar.html'"></div>

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

I was able to filter down the issue to something with ADAL.JS

If I remove the requireadlogin line and the .init lines to configure authentication, the error is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
```

The error is happening when you try to increase the $rootScope.
The error is indicating that he is entering a very large loop and the angular own for security abort your request.

If you wanna add two or more values into a rootscope, why you do not try to use .push function and save all the data into a array?